# How can you import an image from a URL via a function in EtherCalc?

Tags: ethercalc

In EtherCalc I would like to have a barcode generated for each row on the basis of the contents in its first cell. Specifically I would like to get an image back from: `http://www.barcodes4.me/apidocumentation` according to the value held in the first cell of the row and display the image in column B.

Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ethercalc image formula**

```
="{image: http://www.barcodes4.me/barcode/"&B2&"/AnyValueYouWish.png }"
```

this will use the code in cell b2 to create the barcode

see
http://sheet.cellmaster.com.au/example_barcode

**Other examples**

http://sheet.cellmaster.com.au/examples